# How to create a xml node using rapidxml

Tags: c++, linux, rapidxml

Hi I want to create the following xml file in C++ using rapidxml on Linux.
How to add an element which is of type **name**.

```
    <wrapit>
       <mainNode>
          <name>something1</name>
       </mainNode>
    </wrapit>
```

what my code generates looks like following which I don't want.

```
    <wrapit>
       <mainNode>
          <name something1=""/>
       </mainNode>
    </wrapit>
```

I could not find much information for this. Few on wordpress but the xml formats are different.

Code snippet

```
xml_node<>* root = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "mainNode");
doc.append_node(root);
xml_node<>* child = doc.allocate_node(node_element,"name");
child->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("something1"));
root->append_node(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

ugg....

```
xml_node<>* child = doc.allocate_node(node_element,"name","something1");
```

does it.